# How to insert an item to Expression arrary

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can insert an item to Expression array? For example: some code like

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>>[] exprs;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i > 0;
exprs.Add(expr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an array, you need to initialize it first:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>>[] exprs = new Expression<Func<int, bool>>[arrayLength];
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i > 0;
exprs[0] = expr;
```

This just just like any other array type in C#.  For details on arrays, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

If you just need a collection that can grow as needed, consider `List<T>` instead:

```
List<Expression<Func<int, bool>>> exprs = new List<Expression<Func<int, bool>>>();
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i > 0;
exprs.Add(expr);  // This works with List<T> - you don't need the size in advance.
```

Comment: Basicly I'm trying to create an array of Expression<Fun<int, bool>> at runtime, and use it for Expression.Call(). I would like use Dynamic Linq Library now rather than write it from scratch. Thanks for your help.